# Ruby: Selectively parsing YAML doc to recover different classes of object

Tags: ruby, yaml

I'm trying to build some basic object-persistence (save game, load game) into my sandbox app.

I'm using YAML to dump objects to a file, and then I want to recover them. I have two different classes of instantiated objects, and they get written like this, which all seems fine:

```
---
- !ruby/object:Game::Room
    reference: :largecave
    name: Large cave
    description: a large empty cave
    connections:
    :west: :smallcave
    :south: :waterfall
- !ruby/object:Game::Room
    reference: :smallcave
    name: Small cave
    description: a small cave
    connections:
    :east: :largecave
- !ruby/object:Game::Room
    reference: :waterfall
(... etc)
---
- !ruby/object:Game::GameObject
    reference: :key
    name: Key
    description: A small key
    room: :smallcave
- !ruby/object:Game::GameObject
    reference: :bowl
(....etc)
```

The problem comes trying to recover and populate the two different arrays of objects:

```
YAML.load(datastore.read)
```

works fine but is only good for one class of object, and I've tried the select method, like this, but without success:

```
@rooms = datastore.select("!ruby/object:Game::Room")
@objects = datastore.select("!ruby/object:Game::GameObject")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "only good for one class object"?

Comment: Well it seems to load everything into one array, but I need to put the Room objects into rooms array, and the GameObjects into gameobjects array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a suggestion for data-usability, I'd recommend creating some methods for your classes to generate hashes of the contents of an object. That way you can store YAML representations of hashes, which are universal, rather than Ruby objects, which are only usable in Ruby, not other languages.

I'd forgo creating multiple documents in your YAML file and would use something like:

```
require 'pp'
require 'yaml'

places =   [
  {
    reference: :largecave,
    name: 'Large cave',
    description: 'a large empty cave',
    connections: {
      west: :smallcave,
      south: :waterfall
    }
  },
  {
    reference: :smallcave,
    name: 'Small cave',
    description: 'a small cave',
    connections: {
      east: :largecave
    }
  },
  {
    reference: :waterfall
  }
]

things = [
  {
    reference: :key,
    name: 'Key',
    description: 'A small key',
    room: :smallcave
  },
  {
    reference: :bowl
  }
]

data = [
  places,
  things
]

puts data.to_yaml
```

Which outputs:

```
---
- - :reference: :largecave
    :name: Large cave
    :description: a large empty cave
    :connections:
      :west: :smallcave
      :south: :waterfall
  - :reference: :smallcave
    :name: Small cave
    :description: a small cave
    :connections:
      :east: :largecave
  - :reference: :waterfall
- - :reference: :key
    :name: Key
    :description: A small key
    :room: :smallcave
  - :reference: :bowl
```

Looking at the data after a round-trip through YAML-land:

```
places, things = YAML.load(data.to_yaml)

=> [[{:reference=>:largecave,
  :name=>"Large cave",
  :description=>"a large empty cave",
  :connections=>{:west=>:smallcave, :south=>:waterfall}},
  {:reference=>:smallcave,
  :name=>"Small cave",
  :description=>"a small cave",
  :connections=>{:east=>:largecave}},
  {:reference=>:waterfall}],
[{:reference=>:key,
  :name=>"Key",
  :description=>"A small key",
  :room=>:smallcave},
  {:reference=>:bowl}]]

pp places

[{:reference=>:largecave,
  :name=>"Large cave",
  :description=>"a large empty cave",
  :connections=>{:west=>:smallcave, :south=>:waterfall}},
{:reference=>:smallcave,
  :name=>"Small cave",
  :description=>"a small cave",
  :connections=>{:east=>:largecave}},
{:reference=>:waterfall}]

pp things

[{:reference=>:key,
  :name=>"Key",
  :description=>"A small key",
  :room=>:smallcave},
{:reference=>:bowl}]
```

You could also take advantage of [YAML::Store](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/Store.html) and do it like:

```
require 'yaml/store'
require 'pp'

store = YAML::Store.new('objects.store')
store.transaction do
  store['places'] = places
  store['things'] = things
end

places = things = nil

store.transaction(true) do
  places = store['places']
  things = store['things']
end

pp places
pp things
```

Which looks like:

```
[{:reference=>:largecave,
  :name=>"Large cave",
  :description=>"a large empty cave",
  :connections=>{:west=>:smallcave, :south=>:waterfall}},
{:reference=>:smallcave,
  :name=>"Small cave",
  :description=>"a small cave",
  :connections=>{:east=>:largecave}},
{:reference=>:waterfall}]

[{:reference=>:key,
  :name=>"Key",
  :description=>"A small key",
  :room=>:smallcave},
{:reference=>:bowl}]
```

YAML::Store will create your YAML file on disk for you:

```
---
places:
- :reference: :largecave
  :name: Large cave
  :description: a large empty cave
  :connections:
    :west: :smallcave
    :south: :waterfall
- :reference: :smallcave
  :name: Small cave
  :description: a small cave
  :connections:
    :east: :largecave
- :reference: :waterfall
things:
- :reference: :key
  :name: Key
  :description: A small key
  :room: :smallcave
- :reference: :bowl
```

Which is basically a hash, where `places` and `things` are the keys to the embedded data.

Storing the configuration of "Adventure" in a YAML file might become unwieldy, so you might want to look into using something like [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) and a SQLite database eventually. You could store the data in a common format still, but it'd also be set up for fast random access and wouldn't need to be contained in memory.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks. By the way (if you didn't already know) the game is a further development from Peter Cooper's 'Beginning Ruby'.

Comment: I'm not sure it's brilliant, but thanks. I just hate seeing data be tied to one application. Take advantage of YAML's ability to serialize data in a fairly universal manner, and you can do more with it.